# Holy Objects of a Messianic

Tags: halacha, tefilin, tzitzis, tallit-gadol, heresy

[Messianic Judaism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messianic_Judaism) is a heretical offshoot of Judaism which maintains that Jesus was the Mashiach which *may* violate the prohibition of avodah zarah (see above link). Would the tefillin or tallit* used by a Messianic be assur to use as a result and how would they be treated?

---

*Assuming it has none of their iconography, see [here](http://holylandshopping.com/p38/Prayer_shawl_messianic_Christian_Sign_tallit_Hebrew_English72*22/product_info.html) for a particularly strong example.

Comment: Used or [written](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29459/5323)?

Comment: I believe it would be more accurate to say "'Messianic Judaism' is a offshoot of evangelical Christianity that incorporates a variety of Jewish practices and beliefs while retaining the belief that Jesus is the Messiah."

Comment: @Yirmeyahu, agreed, although many are Jewish-ish minim and kofrim, hence the classification.

Comment: @Shokhet, written the assur, I know, but used, because messianics might be avdei avodah zarah.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Aright....maybe you should consider editing that idea of תקרובת \ משמשי עבודה זרה into the question to make that point clearer.

Comment: Off-hand, there might be a difference between how we treat a messianic's tallis and his tefillin because of "divrei torah einam mikablim tuma"

Comment: Was the Tefilin written by a Jew or by the fellow who is a member of the messianic sect?

Comment: @GershonGold, As I have no clue about what they use, I am assuming that they are tefillin made by yirei shamayim according to halacha.

Comment: @GershonGold I'm not so sure there is a Messianic sofer. I think generally they just purchase these kind of things from mainstream Jewish providers.(Usually online from my experience talking with them. Such is the danger of online Judaica joints; you never know who you're selling to)

Comment: @Yirmeyahu so it's an offshoot of a heretical offshoot of Judasim ;)

Comment: @Sabbahillel, I rolled back your edit because I felt that it was unnecessary

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt ok the version that I saw had Jew at the end of the heading. That is why I italicized it. I would call them *messy-antics*